# Cannot display results from query with PDO

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get the results from a query which should get multiple results and display them all on the page. However it is not displaying any of the content. My guess is a mistake in my syntax for me loop. But I am unsure.

```
//query to find comments about this map
$query = "
        SELECT 
           user_id,
           comment
         FROM map_comments
         WHERE
           map_id = :mapID
         ";  

//query parameters
$query_params = array(
  ':mapID' => $_SESSION['mapID']
);

try
{
    //execute query
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $statement->execute($query_params);
    //get all results
    $comments = $result->fetchAll;
    if($result === FALSE) 
    { 
      die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die("failed to find comments");
}

foreach($comments as &$comment)
      { 
        echo $comment;
      }
```

Comment: `die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling` - Yeah well... for sure you need "better" handling, as in PDO and not mysql_ here. We also don't know what API you're using to connect with, or if you started the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses after a function to call it.

```
$comments = $result->fetchAll;
```

should be:

```
$comments = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Also, the check for `if ($result == FALSE)` should be **before** this line. And you can't use `mysql_error()` if you're using PDO, you should use `$statement->errorInfo()`. Or you should enable `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` on the connection, and the `catch` block will be invoked. You should then use `$db->errorInfo()` in the error message that it prints.

Comment: thank you very much, but now I am getting an error saying fetch all is being used on a non-object

Comment: It should be `$statement->fetchAll()`.

Comment: thank you for the help, I am very new to this, it is now displaying 'Array' for the value of each comment, and it is saying I am trying an array to string conversion as the error, any idea why this is the case?

Comment: `$fetchAll` returns a 2-dimensional array. So each `$comment` is an array containing one row of the results. When you try to echo an array, it converts it to a string containing the word `Array`. Use `var_dump` for arrays, or just echo `$comment['comment']` if you just want to see the comment field without the `user_id`.